I can't use command Get-MgApplication via Microsoft Graph
I am using this code to connect:
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication

$body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials";
    client_id = "feabd295-fd7d-45d1-8b5a-97f2abf4fe0e";
    client_secret = "<hidden>";
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/52da6ceb-c432-45d8-9cee-97902996ced9/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body

$accessToken = $response.access_token

$clientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $accessToken -AsPlainText -Force 

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $clientSecret*

The client has Application.Read.All is it's API permission but I am getting this error:
Get-MgApplication_List: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied
Date: 2024-06-07T14:52:33

Headers:
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Vary                          : Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
request-id                    : 16af9717-1979-4df8-a630-19a1a6ae8eb6
client-request-id             : c8e4d80e-c4ed-4285-b611-49781d4c70b8
x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"UK South","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"004","RoleInstance":"LO1PEPF0000310D"}}
x-ms-resource-unit            : 2
Date                          : Fri, 07 Jun 2024 14:52:33 GMT*

Tried the command Get-MgApplication and got this result:
Get-MgApplication_List: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied
Date: 2024-06-07T14:52:33

Headers:
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Vary                          : Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
request-id                    : 16af9717-1979-4df8-a630-19a1a6ae8eb6
client-request-id             : c8e4d80e-c4ed-4285-b611-49781d4c70b8
x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"UK South","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"004","RoleInstance":"LO1PEPF0000310D"}}
x-ms-resource-unit            : 2
Date                          : Fri, 07 Jun 2024 14:52:33 GMT*


I would suggest starting with Get-MgContext and check the authentication context of the session is what you are expecting and also that you have the correct scopes being returned.


Get-MgApplication_List: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied
Date: 2024-06-07T14:52:33

The above error indicates you don't have permission to get the list of Microsoft applications.
In my environment, I created application with name sample-venkat  and assigning Application.Read.All API permission in the portal.
Portal:

Now, When I tried with same script with Get-MgApplication it executed successfully.
Script:
$body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials";
    client_id = "9ccxxxxx3a6";
    client_secret = "xxxxIL";
    scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/22xxxxfb-9bbfa7d40283/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body
$accessToken = $response.access_token

$token = ConvertTo-SecureString $accessToken -AsPlainText -Force 

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token
Get-MgApplication | 
  Format-List Id, DisplayName, AppId, SignInAudience, PublisherDomain

Output:
Id              : 004792xxxxxa2c1f17a
DisplayName     : StorageSP
AppId           : b3cxx7f0721b37
SignInAudience  : AzureADMyOrg
PublisherDomain : xxxxxonmicrosoft.com

Id              : 01ce6xxxxx
DisplayName     : EnumerateAppInsights
AppId           : a215a09xxx7b
SignInAudience  : AzureADMyOrg
PublisherDomain : xxxxonmicrosoft.com


I agree with Glen Scales' comment that you can use the Get-MgContext command to verify whether your application is connected to scope or not.
Command and output:
PS C:\Users\xxxx> Get-MgContext


ClientId               : 9ccxxxxx54f1d3a6
TenantId               : 226cfxxxxx9bbfa7d40283
Scopes                 : {Application.Read.All}
AuthType               : UserProvidedAccessToken
TokenCredentialType    : UserProvidedAccessToken
CertificateThumbprint  : 
CertificateSubjectName : 
Account                : 
AppName                : samplevenkat
ContextScope           : Process
Certificate            : 
PSHostVersion          : 5.1.22621.2506
ManagedIdentityId      : 
ClientSecret           : 
Environment            : Global


Reference:
Get-MgApplication (Microsoft.Graph.Applications) | Microsoft Learn
